# How to do Sonar Bit Bucket OAuth Integration

Tags: oauth, integration, bitbucket, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I installed Sonar on my machine.I have Bit Bucket Repository also.How do i perform Sonar Bit Bucket OAuth Integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Bitbucket Authentication Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Bitbucket+Authentication+Plugin) (Github: [sonar-auth-bitbucket](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-auth-bitbucket)) seems to be what you're looking for.

> This plugin enables user authentication and Single Sign-On via Bitbucket.

Comment: Right, looks like there hasn't been any release yet. Well, you could still build a snapshot version and [manually install it](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+a+Plugin) in the meantime (it might be unstable since it's not released), answer edited with link to sources.

Comment: can u suggest me from where i can download manually jar file for  Bitbucket Authentication Plugin.I have not find